# Change frame rate in paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

In Paper.js, is it possible to change the frame rate of the `onFrame(event)`function? The paper.js website tutorial says the function is by default called 60 times per second, but it does not include if it is possible (and how) to change the frame rate of this function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but you can easily *skip* frames in the code within your `onFrame` function.

---

#### Example:

The following code emulates a 30 fps frame rate by skipping frames with an odd number, effectively halving the frame rate.

```
function onFrame(event) {
  if (event.count % 2 === 0) {
    //your code here
  }
}
```